# How can I move the camera directly under a certain plane?

Tags: opengl, java, glsl, lwjgl

I am attempting to render a "reflection" of a scene for water:

[image]

To create this illusion, I need to render the scene from below, and then ignore all geometry below the water line.

[image]

As such, I need to move the camera below the water, and invert the pitch.

I have one problem: My entire framework is based on the fixed-function pipeline. Basically, I need to call the correct glTranslatef() calls and glRotatef() calls to be able to simulate the camera being in the new position, and then render the scene.

Unfortunately, I have so far failed to achieve this. Calling the glRotatef() function obviously just rotates the entire scene, so I am struggling to just simulate the camera rotation.

The water is at a height of 300. I believe I may be moving the camera down correctly by calling `glTranslatef(0, -(2 * (camera.y() - 300)))`, but it has been impossible for me to get them to both work.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this will be helpful for you but there is a really simple way how to achieve a reflection in water.

Using fixed pipeline all you need is to make water transparent (using `GL_BLEND`) and then render the scene upside down (using `glScale(1,-1,1)`). To prevent rendering objects above the water you can use `glClipPlane`.

For example:

```
glScalef(1,-1,1); //everything is now rendered upside down
double plane[4] = {0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0}; //water at y=0
glEnable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0);
glClipPlane(GL_CLIP_PLANE0, plane); //preventing rendering objects above the water
RenderSceneAgain(); //renders scene once again
glDisable(GL_CLIP_PLANE0);
glScalef(1,-1,1); //everything is now rendered normally again
```

Its really one of the simplest way to achieve reflections and because you have to render your scene twice you can expect performance drop.

Comment: I really like the idea of rendering everything upside down, but unfortunately that just isn't the case. I'm above the terrain still, because scaling the object simply moves the coordinates lower rather than actually flipping the object.